# Parse server cloud code not responding on any query

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I recently migrated parseserver to heroku, and everything seems to work perfectly except in my Cloud Code any Parse.Query does not seem to ever respond.

I can run custom cloud code, however anytime I need to run a Parse.Query the request times out.

here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("get_remaining_minutes", function(request, response) {

var config_name = "RWMTrialMinutes";
var minutesForPeriod = 120;
var isTrial = true;
var periodStartDate = new Date("01/01/2015");
var minutesUsed = 0;

console.log("userId=" + request.params.userId);
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

userQuery.get({ useMasterKey: true }).then(request.params.userId, {
    success: function(user) {
       console.log("success");
        response.success(100);
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
        console.log("failed");
        response.error(error);
    }
});
});
```

I then call: 
    curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" https://xxx.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/get_remaining_minutes?userId=dMbBrRGD1y

and get a timeout

2016-10-13T17:21:21.858269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/classes/_User" host=xxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=225
2016-10-13T17:21:21.788404+00:00 app[web.1]: userId=dMbBrRGD1y
2016-10-13T17:21:51.759088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/parse/functions/get_remaining_minutes?userId=dMbBrRGD1y" host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0

I've tried many different ways to query - tried .first, .get, .find, all seem to do the same thing - timeout. If i skip the .get call, the function works fine and I can response.success correctly. However I obviously need to make the query for my code to work.

I feel like i'm missing something basic, like a require or maybe a path is not set up correctly.

I will also mention I am running parse server and dashboard on the same Heroku application if you think that makes a difference as to why the cloud code is failing.

Any ideas?

Edit: adding my index.js code for starting parse-server and dashboard

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var path = require('path');

var allowInsecureHTTP = true;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;


var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xxx',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'xxx.herokuapp.com/parse',
  restAPIKey: 'xxx',
push:{
ios:{
      pfx: 'Push.p12',
      bundleId: 'xxx',
      production: true
     }
   }
}, allowInsecureHTTP);

var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
users: [{
   user: 'admin',
  pass: 'xxx'
 }],
apps: [
 {
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL + process.env.PARSE_MOUNT ||      'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
  appName: process.env.APP_NAME || 'StoryTime',
  iconName: 'Icon-60.png'
   }
 ],
 "iconsFolder": "icons"
 }, allowInsecureHTTP);

var app = express();

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));


var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

//start the dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);

 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-    server repo on GitHub!');
 });


var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

Comment: And how do you start the parse server? Show us the config, you should define the file for cloud code there

Comment: i've updated the question to include my express code to start parse-server and dashboard.

Comment: Turns out there were two problems - first the server was configured incorrectly. the SERVER_URL did not have /parse on it - and because the PARSE_MOUNT property was being used to route in express, I missed it. 

Second the syntax for useMasterKey needs to be like this for .get() - I had copied the code from somewhere online and it was not correct.

userQuery.get(request.params.userId, { useMasterKey:true, 
        success: function(user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were two problems - first the server was configured incorrectly. the SERVER_URL did not have /parse on it - and because the PARSE_MOUNT property was being used to route in express, I missed it. Second the syntax for useMasterKey needs to be like this for .get() - I had copied the code from somewhere online and it was not correct.

```
userQuery.get(request.params.userId, { useMasterKey:true, success: function(user)....
```